# Array as Pointers when using a 2D Char Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I'm looking over a practice problem and I don't understand how the c++ arrives at the answers it gives me. I understand how pointers work with an array when it's initialized as an "int" type but I'm completely thrown off when it's a "char" type. What is different about char that gives me the results I'm seeing?

Also why are b and &b the same? When I ask for b I assume it's the same as asking for the address of the array which is the first element of b right? Also when adding to b I'm asking for the address of that element correct?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char b[5][7];

    cout<<sizeof(b)<<endl; //output 35

    cout<<sizeof(b+1)<<endl; //output 8

    cout<<sizeof(*(b+1))<<endl; //output 7

    cout<<"the address of b is"<<b<<endl;

    cout<<"the address of b+2 is"<<b+2<<endl;

    cout<<"the address of &b is"<<&b<<endl;

    cout<<"the address of &b+2 is"<<&b+2<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a special overload for `char *` but not for any other pointer types, this is for outputting C-style strings. In fact you used it to output the text `"the address of b is"` !